# pivotal/LicenseFinder returns "No dependencies recognized!" for Gradle project

Tags: gradle

I have an android project in which I'd like to use license_finder to generate a license report for my application.

I have the followed the instructions at[`pivotal/LicenseFinder`](https://github.com/pivotal/LicenseFinder) and have a build.gradle file that looks like this

```
plugins {
    id "com.github.hierynomus.license-report" version"0.15.0"
}

...

downloadLicenses {
    dependencyConfiguration "compile"
}
```

Since license_finder is installed using `gem` and build.gradle is configured, I now run `lincense_finder` and get the following error

```
[admin@localhost android-client]$ license_finder
LicenseFinder::Gradle: is active

No dependencies recognized!
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: I've got the same problem and created a GitHub issue (https://github.com/pivotal/LicenseFinder/issues/647).

Answer (score 0):

You should add the following line:

```
apply plugin: "com.github.hierynomus.license"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).